# Measurability of multipartite entanglement

Tags: quantum-information

Consider an arbitrary quantum system of $N$ distinguishable channels, where each channel can be considered a beam ending in a photon counter for simplicity

How completely can the multipartite entanglement be caracterized by observations? are there limits on the ability to do a complete entanglement tomography? a limitation would be, for example, the number of measurements required for a full characterization growing exponentially with the number of channels

Comment: I think it would help if you would make your question more precise, e.g. by writing some formulas.

Comment: what formulas would you like to see?

Comment: Well, it would be good to have a precise description of the setup.  E.g., a channel is something which takes a quantum system and maps it to another quantum system. Is this relevant? Or are you just saying that you have N photons (in N beams), i.e., N qubits, and can measure each qubit individually?

Comment: yeah, that is what I meant. I had no concrete setup, other that the beams are separate

Comment: Well, then you should maybe update your question accordingly so it becomes clear what you are looking for. Also, what do you mean by "complete entanglement tomography"? Fully complete tomography would e.g. indeed require an exponentially growing number of measurements (as the state itself is specified by exponentially many numbers).